# Eclipse (kepler) doesn't show structure members

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, nested, structure

I am pretty new to eclipse, therefore what may seem obvious to others is to me a mystery, and of course I'm sorry for that.
While building project under Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (Version: Kepler Service Release 1, Build id: 20130919-0819 on Win 7 64bit) and MinGW toolchain, debugger variables view doesn't want to show me couple of things. It starts as I define structure within structure, like this:

```
typedef     struct
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
}ts;


typedef struct
{
    int i;
    ts  s1;
    ts  s2;
}t_mystruct;
```

I get this in a variable view of the debugger:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

I could do relatively much (thanks to google and stackoverflow) with all the headaches eclipse gave me till now, but this one seems to be a little tougher, not even google would say much about this. So it's either new, or that obvious, that only a eclipse novice like myself could have troubles there.

---

Second question would be why is there an empty space, where I would like to see members of a s1 structure?
It seems always to favor the first structure I open to view, and the second one is always blank space - this couldn't be any convenient in any possible way :(
The same goes for the memory view - if it's a nested structure member can't open the memory view for it due to false/unknown address.

I do think, that debugger should have some kind of a parsing troubles with those structures, but unluckily for me, I don't know which thread to pull first.

[Link to the full project code.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/722bg4h48ssxhva/struct-test.eclipse-debugger.zip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks to my colleague I've found out, that using "Standard Create Process Launcher" instead of GDB (DSF) gives me the opportunity to have a nice bug free (maybe almost) debug session.

[image]

I can live with that as long as I don't know why should I use the other launcher.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the complete answer, but some testing results which hopefully can be helpful:

I tried your example under Kepler SR1 on Linux (Ubuntu) with default toolchain (Linux GCC), and it seems working fine there: [expanded variables on Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QlKb.png)

But under Kepler SR1 on Windows 8 I have the same issues as you: both "no member" and "empty space". By some reason it tries to evaluate the wrong expression (`(mydat).i2` instead of `(mydat).s2.i2`) and receives the corresponding answer from gdb ("There is no member named i2").

This is a small test with gdb in console with expected results: [gdb console test](http://pastebin.com/aXLZsU3v) (see the last 2 commands)

It looks like the UI bugs in Windows version of Eclipse or something.

Comment: Thanks, Alex! Seems like I should pay a visit to eclipse bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the answer provided by Sangesi, to use the "Standard Create Process Launcher" instead of GDB (DSF) works for me too. (I can't Vote Up or Comment on his answer as I do not have enough reputation points yet.)

Verified using Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7, CDT v8.0.2, Cygwin, gdb v7.6.50.